# Make OracleDataSource robust against Database restarts and hickups

Tags: spring, oracle, jms, datasource

So I got a advanced queue working with a Connectionfactory:

```
ConnectionFactory jmsQueueConnectionFactory() throws JMSException, SQLException { 
  final OracleDataSource dataSource = new OracleDataSource();
  dataSource.setUser(username);
  dataSource.setPassword(password);
  dataSource.setURL(url);
  dataSource.setImplicitCachingEnabled(true);
  dataSource.setFastConnectionFailoverEnabled(true);

  return AQjmsFactory.getConnectionFactory(dataSource);
}
```

This is running on a shared Database which might be restarted or sometimes the network just has a short hickup. Which results in no more messages from the Queue.

I use a spring MessageListener to retrieve messages and there is actually no indicator or what so ever that the queue is not running anymore. After restarting the application I then get a load of older messages that should have been processed already.

Is there a way or specific data source implementation which reconnects or something?

Update: Listener Impl

```
@Bean
OracleAqQueueFactoryBean etlQueueFactory() throws JMSException, SQLException {
    final OracleAqQueueFactoryBean bean = new OracleAqQueueFactoryBean();
    bean.setConnectionFactory(jmsQueueConnectionFactory());
    bean.setOracleQueueUser("USER");
    bean.setOracleQueueName("QUEUE");
    return bean;
}


@Bean
DefaultMessageListenerContainer jmsContainer() throws JMSException, SQLException {
    final DefaultMessageListenerContainer bean = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
    bean.setConnectionFactory(jmsQueueConnectionFactory());
    bean.setDestination(etlQueueFactory().getObject());
    bean.setMessageListener(new MyListener());
    bean.setSessionTransacted(false);
    return bean;
}

public class MyListener implements MessageListener {
    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have to do it on the JMS level, not DB level.

Not sure what type of listener you are using, but a [DefaultMessageListenerContainer](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/DefaultMessageListenerContainer.html) in Spring is implemented with a consumer.receive(timeout) loop. It's more robust than using a plain listener as it will attempt to reconnect on each poll cycle (if needed).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I updated the Question with the rest of the config. I use the DefaultMessageListenerContainer which gets a Class that implemens MessageListener. After DB restart the onMessage seems not to be active anymore.